# What is meaning of Buddha and how he called Buddha?

Tags: the-buddha

By marathi language "Buddhi" means intellectual so what is meaning of "Buddha" or is same as Buddhi? Does people started call him Buddha ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Does people started call him Buddha ?**

It's according to the suttas that he told people to remember him as "Buddha". For example, at the end of the [Dona Sutta (AN 4.36)](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an04/an04.036.than.html):

> Remember me, brahman, as 'awakened.'
>
> ... and so, brahman,
> I'm awake.

Alternatively [the Dharmafarer translation of this sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/36.13-Pada-Dona-S-a4.36-piya.pdf):

> Therefore, brahmin, remember me as the Buddha.”
>
> ... therefore, brahmin, am I buddha.

The Pali for that last line:

> *tasmā buddho’smi brāhmaṇâ ti*

"Buddha" isn't the only word used; for example there's also *tathagata*.

Answer (score 5):

Definition of Buddha based on Pali Dictionary is [here](http://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/buddha):

> Buddha Skt., Pali, lit., “awakened one.”

The Wikipedia entry is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddha_(title)):

> The word Buddha means "awakened one" or "the enlightened one".
>
> Hypothetical root budh "perceive" 1. Pali buddha – "understood, enlightened", masculine "the Buddha"; Aśokan (the language of the Inscriptions of Aśoka) Budhe nominative singular; Prakrit buddha – ‘ known, awakened ’; Waigalī būdāī, "truth"; Bashkarīk budh "he heard"; Tōrwālī būdo preterite of bū, "to see, know" from bṓdhati; Phalūṛa búddo preterite of buǰǰ , "to understand" from búdhyatē; Shina Gilgitī dialect budo, "awake"; Gurēsī dialect budyōnṷ intransitive "to wake"; Kashmiri bọ̆du, "quick of understanding (especially of a child)"; Sindhī ḇudho, past participle (passive) of ḇujhaṇu, "to understand" from búdhyatē, West Pahāṛī buddhā, preterite of bujṇā, "to know"; Sinhalese buj (j written for d), budu, bud, but, "the Buddha".

Buddha means one who understood or awakened. This understanding / awakening is based on intelligence gained.